# Jaxen library is not getting loaded in the classpath, so dom4j throws noclassdeffound error

Tags: java, dom4j

I am using Dom4j lib, which has been loaded by the jetty server itself. The dom4j depends on jaxen.jar library for some of the things, I have loaded this library in my application but the jaxen jar is not getting picked (I use a maven project and I add the dependency in the pom). so it throws noclassdeffound error

I did a quick google search and it revealed I had to add the jaxen.jar in the server lib, why should it be added to the server lib and not in the client lib?

Any response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Figured out the issue. It is because the parent classloader which is loading dom4j is not loading jaxen jar. Eventhough I load these jars in the child classloader, java class loader checks with parent classloader and it throws noclassdeffound error

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. It is because the parent classloader which is loading dom4j is not loading jaxen jar. Eventhough I load these jars in the child classloader, java class loader checks with parent classloader and it throws noclassdeffound error